# Sitecore rendering: searching of first item by condition using fields

Tags: xslt, xpath, sitecore

I have few items with parent/children dependencies:

Item1 -> Item2 -> Item3

They have fields with the same name: "Main Info". Some of them have this field filled, some of them with empty "Main Info". Main goal: if page with filled "Main Info" selected - show this info. If page with empty "Main Info" selected - show info from ancestor.
So i have rendering:

```
<xsl:variable name="home" select="$sc_currentitem/ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@template, 'page') and @Main Info != '']" />

<!-- entry point -->
<xsl:template match="*">  
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$home" mode="main"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="main">    
  <sc:text field="Right Footer Text"  />
</xsl:template>
```

This shows nothing.

```
<xsl:variable name="home" select="$sc_currentitem/ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@template, 'page')]" />

<xsl:template match="*">  
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$home" mode="main"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="main">    
  <sc:text field="Right Footer Text"  />
</xsl:template>
```

This shows "Main Info" from every ancestor of selected item.

How can i get only one "Main Info"? From selected item if this field isn't empty or from  first parent item with "Main Info" filled.

Comment: For performance reasons you should consider writing your control in C#, not in XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance-wise you might not want to use the `ancestor-or-self` selector. If you have a lot of items and a deep tree its bad for performance.

I think I'd either create an `<xsl:choose>` like so:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="sc:fld('main info',.)!=''">
    <sc:text field="main info" select="." /> <!-- Display main info from item -->
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <sc:text field="main info" select=".." /> <!-- Display main info from parent -->
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Of course, if there's a possibility that it's not the parent but the parents parent (and so forth) that has the main info I'd make it simpler by creating my own XSL Extension.
You can read more on XSL Extensions on this [article](http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/Developers/Articles/2009/06/how%20to%20XSLExtensions.aspx) by Jens Mikkelsen.

Comment: Thanks! Xsl Extension it is what i need! Works great!

Answer (score 2):

I really believe this demonstrates why you should be looking at writing your components in C# as opposed to wasting time trying to "hack" a solution in via XSLT. Sure, you can write your own extension if you like - but let's consider how little code this would be to begin with.

On your .ASCX file, you would have this:

```
<sc:Text runat="server" ID="sctMainInfo" Field="main info" />
```

And in your .cs codebehind/codebeside:

```
Sitecore.Data.Item myItem = Sitecore.Context.Item; // Should be your Datasource item
while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myItem["main info"]))
{
    myItem = myItem.Parent; // you need to add a check here, 
                            // so you don't move up past your Site Root node 
}

sctMainInfo.Item = myItem;
```

By far simpler than a combined XSLT/XSL Helper approach, and performance will be a lot better.

One last thing. The very premise of your rendering has a problem. You shouldn't really be crawling through the item hierarchy to find content for your component, you prevent any possibilities for performing M/V testing or personalizing the component. This is a story for a different day however.